# Java Desktop Integration: open a file with a custom application

Tags: java

how can I open a file from within a java program with a custom application?

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

opens the file only with the systems default application. What I need is something like

```
open(myapp, file);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the target application accepts files to open as arguments, then you could do the following:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec("CustomApp "+filename);
```

Comment: seems to be working, but I get the error `cannot run program: ... error 13 permission denied`

Comment: @EikeCochu Glad it worked. Make sure you have the proper rights to run the application.